# PythonのSKlearn実行時のエラーについて

Tags: python, python3

sklearnを実行して機械学習のテキスト学習していたら以下のエラーが出ました。
どうしたら回避できるかアドバイスをお願いします。
なお、記載のコードは書籍に記載されているコードを入力して実行しています。
各種、必要なライブラリーなどもテキスト通りインストールはしています。

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import svm, datasets, model_selection

iris = datasets.load_iris()

x = iris.data
y = iris.target

svc = svm.SVC(C=1, kerne1="rbf", gamma=0.001)
```

実行結果

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-3ab815fd6dea> in <module>
     10 
     11 #　機械学習アルゴリズムSVMを使用します。
---> 12 svc = svm.SVC(C=1, kerne1="rbf", gamma=0.001)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kerne1'
```

Answer (score 1):

SVC関数にkerne1という引数が定義されていないからです。
kernelと変更してみてください

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html

Comment: kernelへの変更でエラーが解消されました！
ありがとうございます。